# What operator lowers the total angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, operators

Assume  states $|j,m\rangle$, say $j\in\{3,2,1,0\}$, initially at $3$.

Is there any "lowering" operator I could apply such that $L_-|j,m\rangle
=
|j-1,m\rangle
$?

How to express it in the $J_z$ basis?

Comment: The lowering operator is just the adjoint operator (hermitian conjugate for a matrix operator) of the raising operator.

Comment: You ask how to define an operator and express it in the $J_z$ basis... but you literally already did that in the question. Writing $L_- |j, m \rangle = |j-1, m \rangle$ _is_ a definition of an operator that lowers $j$ in the basis you wanted (though it isn't the usual definition of "$L_-$"). What more do you want?

Comment: The Runge–Lenz vector has components failing to commute with the Casimir, so taking you out of a fixed j multiplet. You must first calculate the freak operator  with eigenvalues j in terms of the Casimir whose eigenvalues  are j(j+1), and then construct a lowering operator for it. Possibly out of LRL pieces. Context?

Comment: @CosmasZachos so, we need a bigger degenerate state space? but we should be able to do that with physical meanings consider all the states were there already.

Comment: Look at [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89659/eigenfunctions-of-the-runge-lenz-vector).

Comment: So you are considering the 3rd excited state of hydrogen? LRL connects all degenerate multiplets among themselves.

Comment: Consider [Burkhardt & Leventhal 2004](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241050165_Lenz_vector_operations_on_spherical_hydrogen_atom_eigenfunctions).

Answer (score 4):

First you need to define the operator whose eigenvalues are *j*. As your avatar invites me to, I skip the fine formal fussing and just calculate instead. Such operators are routine, e.g., [Curtright and Zachos (1990) PhysLettB243](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cosmas_Zachos/publication/222263889_Deforming_maps_for_quantum_algebras/links/5c03e35d45851523d15942f8/Deforming-maps-for-quantum-algebras.pdf). For the Casimir $\vec J \cdot \vec  J$, with eigenvalues *j(j+1)*, define
$$
L_0\equiv \frac{\sqrt{1+4\vec J \cdot \vec  J}-1}{2},
$$
with eigenvalues *j*,
$$
L_0| j,m\rangle = j| j,m\rangle .
$$

Your target operator $L_-$ should distinctly fail to commute with the Casimir, and hence $L_0$, so as to take you from a fixed *j* to a lower one, just as the LRL vectors do in the Hydrogen atom! That is
$$
[L_-,L_0]= L_- \\
[L_-,J_z]=0,
$$
so that 
$$
L_0(L_- |j,m\rangle)= (j-1)(L_- |j,m\rangle),\\
J_z (L_- |j,m\rangle) =m(L_- |j,m\rangle),
$$
as per your posit.

You might construct such operators, with pain, out of pieces of [LRL invariants](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/what-symmetry-causes-the-runge-lenz-vector-to-be-conserved), such as $A_z$, but without context this readily slips into the slough of mootness.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, any vector operator, i.e. any tensor operator with $\ell=1$ will shift you $\Delta \ell=0,\pm 1$.  Moreover, if your operator is parity-odd, then by Laporte’s rule or by simple properties of the CG coefficient $\Delta l=0$ is excluded. Thus, for instance, the operator $\hat z$ has the property 
\begin{align}
\langle \alpha’\ell’m’\vert z\vert \alpha \ell m\rangle =
C^{\ell’m’}_{\ell m; 10}\frac{\langle \alpha’\ell’\Vert r\Vert \alpha \ell\rangle}{\sqrt{2\ell’+1}}\delta_{m’m}\delta_{\ell’,\ell\pm 1}
\end{align}
by the Wigner-Eckart theorem, with  $C^{\ell’m’}_{\ell m;10}$ a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.

This is not quite what you want since it will shift up or shift down the value of $\ell$.    However, with
\begin{align}
\hat V_\pm=\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat x\pm i\hat y)\, ,\qquad \hat V_0=\hat z
\end{align}
then the sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{km} C^{\ell-1,m’}_{\ell m;1k} \hat V_k\vert\alpha \ell m\rangle \tag{1}
\end{align}
will have non-zero matrix element with only $\vert\alpha’ \ell-1,m’\rangle$.  This can be seen by invoking again the Wigner-Eckart theorem:
\begin{align}
\langle \alpha’\ell’m’\vert\sum_{km} C^{\ell-1,m’}_{\ell m;1k} \hat V_k\vert\alpha \ell m\rangle&=
\sum_{km}. 
\sum_{km} C^{\ell-1,m’}_{\ell m;1k} \langle\alpha’ \ell’m’\vert \hat V_k\vert\alpha \ell m\rangle\, ,\\
&=\sum_{km} C^{\ell-1,m’}_{\ell m;1k} 
C^{\ell’ m’}_{\ell m;1k} 
\frac{\langle\alpha’ \ell’ \Vert \hat V_k\Vert\alpha \ell \rangle}{\sqrt{2\ell’+1}}\, ,\\
&=\frac{\langle\alpha’ \ell’\Vert \hat V_k\Vert\alpha \ell \rangle}{\sqrt{2\ell’+1}}\delta_{\ell’,\ell-1}
\end{align}
by orthogonality of the CGs.  (1) is not a single operator but it does contain a projector to the correct $\ell’$ subspace, and you can freely choose the $m’$ value of your target state.